# How to sort BigDecimals without swapping .12 and 0.12?

Tags: java, sorting, bigdecimal

.12 and 0.12 are being swapped while sorting in descending order. Actually if the same numbers exist they have to be printed in the order they were received in.

> Java's BigDecimal class can handle arbitrary-precision signed decimal
> numbers. Let's test your knowledge of them!
>
> Given an array, `s`, of `n` real number strings, sort them in descending
> order — but wait, there's more! Each number must be printed in the
> exact same format as it was read from stdin, meaning that `.1` is
> printed as `.1`, and `0.1` is printed as `0.1`. If two numbers represent
> numerically equivalent values (eg `.1==0.1`), then they must be listed
> in the same order as they were received as input).

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
String[] s = new String[n + 2];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    s[i] = sc.next();
}
sc.close();

BigDecimal[] d = new BigDecimal[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    d[i] = new BigDecimal(s[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (d[j].compareTo(d[i]) == 1) {
            BigDecimal t = d[i];
            d[i] = d[j];
            d[j] = t;
            String stmp = s[i];
            s[i] = s[j];
            s[j] = stmp;
        }
    }
}

// Output
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(s[i]);
}
```

Input:

```
9
-100
50
0
56.6
90
0.12
.12
02.34
000.000
```

Expected output:

```
90
56.6
50
02.34
0.12
.12
0
000.000
-100
```

Actual output:

```
90
56.6
50
02.34
.12
0.12
0
000.000
-100
```

Comment: Look up *stable sort* algorithms.

Comment: print the array every time two values get swapped - `0.12` is being swapped with a bigger value after `.12`, in this case `02.34` - after that it is never swapped to the front of `.12`

Comment: and be aware that `compareTo` is specified to return a value `> 0` ("a positive integer")  not just `1` if the value is greater - comparing to `1` may not work depending on implementation... use `> 0` (BTW `Arrays.sort()` is stable)

Comment: yes, but according to the problem we have to sort the values which is in the string format if we convert to decimal there is a problem  .1 will converts to 0.1 but we need that as .1 only so i coverted it into decimal and applied swapping on strings values if(d[j].compareTo(d[i]) == 1)
                {
                    BigDecimal t=d[i];
                    d[i]=d[j];
                    d[j]=t;
                    String stmp = s[i];
                    s[i] = s[j];
                    s[j] = stmp;
                }     so sort cannot be applied here, is there any other ways

Answer (score 0):

I recommand to try a code with sort like this :

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;

class Solution{

    public static void main(String []argh)
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String []s=new String[n];
       
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            s[i] = sc.next();
        }
       
       Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<Object>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Object a1, Object a2) {
           BigDecimal bigDec1 = new BigDecimal((String)a1);
           BigDecimal bigDec2 = new BigDecimal((String)a2);
           return bigDec2.compareTo(bigDec1);
       }
       });
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }

    }


}
```

a simple sort with comparator solve all the problem.

Comment: no need for the cast to string: `Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<>() . . .  compare(String a1, String a2) . . .`  (the compiler can infer the correct type)